# "multiple definition of `main" in eclipse (c- language)

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    cout << "hello world";
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to compile this in Eclipse and it's giving me the error that there are "multiple definitions of main" and I am unable to run it... What should I do?

Comment: Are there other source files in the project that might contain a `main()`?

Comment: Most probably you have more than one source file with `main()` in path - check how to define and use build configurations in **Eclipse** to switch `main()`s in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18926630/multiple-definition-of-main-error-in-eclipse-using-c/40584300#40584300

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to see if there are other source files in your working directory - they may also have main methods in them.